# Sticky Key on Piano Keyboard

Tags: piano, keyboard, maintenance, repair

I have had a keyboard for a while and it has not given me any problems. However, recently, the middle C# on my Yamaha P-155 is sticky. It stays down until I lift it up. When I play the note again, it stays down. It also seems like it is leaning towards the left as well. I have tried pulling it up and moving it to the right, to reposition it, however, after playing it once or twice, it stays stuck down.

Because of lockdown, I am unable to take it to a repair shop. Are there any at-home ways of fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: If it was mine, I'd strip down to where I could see what's happening - at least get to the fulcrum point. Maybe take pics at each stage, for future reference. Maybe something's dropped between two keys, or it needs a little lube, or a spring's come adrift. The only way to find out is to get stripping.

Comment: What Tim says. There's no way to fix it without opening it.  Be careful.

Comment: A Google serarch for "Yamaha P-155 Service Manual" returned some promising results, I'd suggest seeing of one of those pans out.  There's also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMQre0RHc48 which is titled "Fixing a sticky key on a Yamaha piano" (or words to that effect.)

Comment: I had the exact same problem with P-80, and the keys really need to be replaced. For me the stuck keys stopped only after all keys were replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most quality electronic keyboard are built with a framework of alignment pins to help keep the keys in proper alignment with each other. Just going by what you have described, I would guess that the alignment pin for that key has been bent and needs to be straightened back to its proper position. To do this requires disassembly and removal of the key or set of keys affected by the bent pin. Once you have access to the bent pin, it can usually be straightened with pliers, but care must be taken to avoid breaking the pin off. Another possibility is that some alignment pins have a small rubber collar on them to eliminate the plastic clicking of the keys when they are being played. These collars can wear out and break allowing them to become jammed in the mechanism and causing the key to move out of position. In this instance, you'll need to order new replacement parts from the manufacturer in order to repair the instrument.